# Python WindRose plot legend "greater than" sign shows up as inverted question mark

Tags: python, windrose

I'm attempting to plot a wind rose, and for some reason, the greater than (>) symbol is not rendering on the maximum value label, and instead is being printed as an inverted question mark.

I've tried updating windrose, including to the [latest development version](https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose?tab=readme-ov-file). Surely there's a way to define these labels manually, but I can't fathom what's causing this issue. I am stumped.

[image: WindRose Plot]

Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from windrose import WindroseAxes

theta = [0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300]
speed = [10, 0, 10, 40, 50, 40]

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(theta, speed)
ax.set_legend(units='ms$^-$$^1$',title="10m Wind Speed")
```